# Open source version of urban dictionary type platform

Tags: open-source

I want to create a similar website to urban dictionary and am trying to decide on a good starting point.  I'm looking for a nearly identical platform and voting system with registration.  I'm capable of developing but would prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Does something similar exist already in an open source project?